# How to randomly place signal portions to a time series in python?

Tags: python, random, time-series, noise

I have 100 signal portions, which I want to sum them randomly to a time series which is a white noise. i want to finally create a 24 hours time series which these 100 portions is randomly distributed over it. 
I create white noise for 24 hours as below:

```
dt=1/100
nt = 86400 / dt   
t=np.arange(dt,nt*dt,dt)
noise= np.random.randn(len(t))
```

each signal portion is 12 seconds. I do not know how to distribute these 100 portions randomly in created white noise. Also I need to know the exact second which each 100 portion is added to the noise.

Comment: is this python or matlab or something like a programmatic language? Excel? r? you should tag your question with it.

Comment: sure. I editted the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can perhaps be a solution: signal is your array with your 100 portions of signal and timeIndice an array where the signal element i is added to the timeIndice [i] second with noise in the new distribution newDistrib.

```
# signal is your 100 signal portions
dt = 1/100
nt = 86400 / dt   
t = np.arange(dt,nt*dt,dt)
noise = np.random.randn(len(t))

indice = np.array(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(indice)
newDistrib = np.array([noise[i] + signal[i] for i in indice])
timeIndice = indice * 12
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I do not understand what your code is doing actually. Here newDistrib is an array with [400, 1200] samples, while the final signal should has the size of 8640000 because it is one day signal with 86400 seconds and each second has 100 samples.